# Electromagnetic Wave and Photons?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons

An EM wave consists of photons. How are they generated?

It’s my understanding that a radio transceiver creates an oscillating voltage on a conductor matched with a ground; this device being an antenna. Do charged electrons move back and forth at high energy from the conductor to ground? In this process perhaps collide with each other, moving an electron to a higher energy orbital state, then lower state which causes a photon emission at some angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A radio wave is a special form of EM radiation.

In a thermal source, excited electrons "collide with each other, causing an electron to go to a higher energy state and then to a lower energy state, causing photon emission." That's right.

The same thing happens in the antenna rod. The differences with a thermal source are

- the electrons are accelerated synchronously in the same direction, which produces polarized radiation
- the oscillating intensity of the emitted photons depends on the power of the wave generator and the matching of the intended frequency with the length of the antenna rod
- each individual photon moves only a bit along the rod (see drift velocity) and collides many times with other electrons.

The consequence of your question is that a radio wave is an oscillating stream of photons with very different frequencies.

Comment: I think this describes the dual wave-particle theory of light introduced by Einstein, but may not describe the EM wave theory introduced earlier by Maxwell.  For the wave theory, is the EM radiation a transverse wave of electrons with a perpendicular magnetic field? Also, for the dual theory is there a similar field along the photons, or is this EM field only between antenna conductors? Thanks again

Comment: The photon flux from an antenna changes periodically.

In a longitudinal wave (sound wave), the molecules of the carrier medium oscillate back and forth, but ultimately do not move forward. So there are density changes (number of particles per volume) of always the same particles. Density changes also occur with a radio wave, but here it is the periodic emission of new photons that always move forward with c that causes the density change.

Comment: The phenomenal thing about this is that every second change in density of the photon stream is accompanied by a reversal of the direction of the magnetic field and the electric field. Maxwell's equations express this. Einstein "only" noted that the macroscopic effect is based on the emission of quanta when considered in more detail.

Comment: Better you ask a new question. People often talk past each other in comments. ;-)

Comment: I’m still confused by the two theories, are electrons or photons traveling in the wave or both?

Answer (score 1):

**Classical picture**
Classical description of electromagnetic waves emission is based on [Maxwell equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations), which predict that accelerating charges (or, in other words, a current that is changing in time) will emit electromagnetic waves.

Thus, radio emitter consists of a generator that creates current oscillations of a desired frequency, and an antenna, which efficiently couples these oscillations to the transmission channel (which is often just the outside space, but which could be also a metallic wave-guide or an optical fiber).

**Quantum picture**
Quantum description of the emisison is best udnerstood on the example of [lasers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser#Stimulated_emission), where the electrons jump from higher energy levels to lower energy levels and emit the radiation with frequency determined by the energy level spacing:$$\hbar\omega=E_2-E_1.$$(See [the figure in the linked article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser#/media/File:Stimulated_Emission.svg).)

**Why the two seem different**
While the emission of radiation by oscillating electrons in a radio transmitter can be explained in quantum terms, one should not confound the two pictures:

- In the case of a laser (or, in general, the radiation emission by atoms) we are talking about discrete energy levels.
- In case of a radio transmitter we are talking about a metallic antenna, where electrons are free to move, so there are no descrete energies. The emission is due to electrons acceleration and desceleration, which in quantum terms can be explained as [Bremstrahlung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung) - emisison of a continuous spectrum of photons (i.e., photons of many frequencies), which become a well-defined frequency as a result of constructive interference.

Comment: For both theories, does the EM wave consist of electrons or photons or both?

Comment: May we have a discussion that 1. laser light is a EM radiation but not a EM wave, 2. the photons are propagating quanta with oscillating E and B field components, 3. radio *wave* is a) a stream of photons with swelling intensity (because the antenna generator inject oscillating energy into the system) and b) the photons in this stream    are generated due to emission from excited electrons?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler None of these statements is correct... sorry, but this would be a very long discussion.

Comment: @Nick Electromagnetic wave is not electrons. Photons are quanta of electromagnetic radiation, but saying that "EM wave consists of photons" is misleading - it gives a picture of a stream of particles, which is incorrect.

Comment: @RogerVadim It's my understanding the photon is defined as both a particle and wave.  Either Huygens or Young defined light as spherical wavefronts. By quanta of EM radiation, does this place any properties on the particular wavefront of the photon?